# Не очень понятный переход при нажатии на метку, проблема или мне кажется?

Tags: поддержка, избранные-метки

На сайте `StackOverflow на русском` есть возможность отслеживать интересующие вас метки. Если я правильно понял, это было сделано для того чтобы человек видел больше вопросов по интересующей его тематике. Вот например мне интересна мобильная разработка и поэтому я отслеживаю метки: `android`,`android-studio`. Сбоку на главной странице есть игнорируемые и отслеживаемые метки, то есть по факту я так понял можно настроить ленту вопросов по своему вкусу. Но, возможно я неправильно понимаю логику сайта, но при нажатии на отслеживаемую метку я почему-то перехожу не на список вопросов по именно этой метку, а на конкурсные вопросы по этой метке. Может конечно так и нужно, но просто может где-то ошибка.

Я решил написать на всякий случай))

Comment: Ответом, ну ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Нажатие по метке не влияет на текущую вкладку в горизонтальном табе*, т.е. если вы смотрите сейчас конкурсные вопросы и жмете на метку, то перейдете в конкурсные вопросы по этой метке. Если вы смотрите вопросы с сортировкой по голосам, то при клике на метку увидите вопросы по этой метке с сортировкой по голосам и т.д.